# Test Accuracy and ConfMatrix dont match up?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, classification, mnist

I'm doing the "hello world" project involving the MNSIT dataset. But by test accuracy doesn't seem to match with the diagonal of my confusion matrix. I'm not sure if I have a bug somewhere that's causing this or if my accuracy function is not correct.

Here is the model:

```
class MNISTV1(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self,
                input_shape: int,
                hidden_units: int,
                output_shape: int):

    super().__init__()
    self.layer_stack = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Flatten(),
        nn.Linear(in_features=input_shape,
                  out_features=hidden_units),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Linear(in_features=hidden_units,
                  out_features=output_shape),
        nn.ReLU()
    )

  def forward(self, x):
    return self.layer_stack(x)

torch.manual_seed(42)
model_1 = MNISTV1(input_shape=784,
                  hidden_units=256,
                  output_shape=len(train_dataset.classes))
model_1.to(device)
```

Creating getting predicted class labels.

```
from tqdm.auto import tqdm

y_preds = []
model_1.eval()
with torch.inference_mode():
  for X, y in tqdm(test_dataloader, desc="Making Predictions..."):

    X,y = X.to(device), y.to(device)

    pred_logits = model_1(X)

    y_pred = torch.softmax(pred_logits.squeeze(), dim=0).argmax(dim=1)

    y_preds.append(y_pred.cpu())

y_preds_tensor = torch.cat(y_preds)
y_preds_tensor
```

the matrix:

```
from torchmetrics import ConfusionMatrix
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_confusion_matrix

confmat = ConfusionMatrix(task="Multiclass",
                          num_classes=len(classes))
confmat_tensor = confmat(preds=y_preds_tensor,
                         target=test_dataset.targets)

fig, ax = plot_confusion_matrix(conf_mat=confmat_tensor.numpy(),
                                class_names=classes,
                                figsize=(10,7))
```

```
torch.manual_seed(42)
def eval_model(model: torch.nn.Module,
               data_loader: torch.utils.data.DataLoader,
               loss_fn: torch.nn.Module,
               accuracy_fn):
  """ Returns a dictionary containing the results of model predicting on data_loader. """
  loss, acc = 0,0
  model.eval()
  with torch.inference_mode():
    for X,y in tqdm(data_loader):
      # make predictions
      y_pred = model(X)

      # accumulate the loss and acc values per batch
      loss += loss_fn(y_pred, y)
      acc += accuracy_fn(y_true=y,
                         y_pred=y_pred.argmax(dim=1))

    # scale loss and acc to find the average loss/ acc per batch
    loss /= len(data_loader)
    acc  /= len(data_loader)

    return {"model_name": model.__class__.__name__, # only works when model was created with a class
            "model_loss": loss.item(),
            "model_acc": acc}


model_1_results = eval_model(model=model_1,
                             data_loader=test_dataloader,
                             loss_fn=loss_fn,
                             accuracy_fn=accuracy_fn)
model_1_results
```

Accuracy function:

```
def accuracy_fn(y_true, y_pred):
  
    correct = torch.eq(y_true, y_pred).sum().item()
    acc = (correct / len(y_pred)) * 100
    return acc
```

My model gets 98.09% which seems very high considering its not a Conv2D network. But the sum of the diagonal of the matrix only gives me about 86% accuracy.

I thought it could be the way I loaded in the data but I checked the dataloader as well as the dataset to make sure that there was no shuffling involved.

Heres the full code on github: https://github.com/nicosaboonchi/Deep-Learning/blob/main/Classification_with_MNIST_Data.ipynb

Comment: You calculate `y_pred` in two different ways in your train/test loop and in your inferencing code.